# jQuery jsonp ajax call doesn't return results when called over ssl

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, jsonp

I have the following ajax call, called from a ssl page in www.DomainName.com (e.g. https://www.domainname.com/caller.aspx):

```
   $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "https://services.DomainName.com/myService.svc/GetCustomers",
 data: { accNo: accno, count: "35" },
 dataType: "jsonp",
 error: function (xhr, status, error) {
 var test = "";
 var test2 = xhr;
 var test3 = stat;
 var test4 = error;
 },
 success: function (data) {
 var suggestions = [];
 $.each(data, function (i, val) {
 suggestions.push(val);
 });
 add(suggestions);
 }
 })
```

Neither the success nor the error functions are called.

But when I change the service url to not use ssl the call succeeds and returns a list of customers:
    http://services.DomainName.com/myService.svc/GetCustomers

If I paste https://services.DomainName.com/myService.svc/GetCustomers directly in the browser's address bar, a list of customers is returned.  It's the jasonp call that doesnt return a result (nor error) when called over SSL.

Any idea?

Comment: Quick question-is the page that's triggering the `$.ajax` call being served up via https as well, or just http?

Comment: @ataddeini:  The page from which the $.ajax call is served is https as well.  Il adjust the question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the XHR response in Firebug/Webkit Dev Tools?

Comment: @kennis: I did put a breakpoint in the error function; the code never reaches it.  (The breakpoints do work in the "success" function when calling the service over http)

Comment: jQuery doesn't call the error handler for JSONP requests (try making a JSONP call to a non-existent URL. You'll never get an error). You're gonna have to check out the the XHR response.

Comment: If you open `https://services.domain.com/myService.svc/GetCustomers?accNo=1234&count=20&callback=foo`, does it correctly respond with JSON wrapped in a `foo()` function call?

Comment: @kennis:  The result of the $.ajax call is null:   var testXH = $.ajax(.....);  -> testXH is null

Comment: @Dave: Over http the result is wrapped in a foo() function call.  Over https it is not.  I use WCF for the web service.  (The proposed "save as" file name for the http request is GetCustomers.js; for the http request it is GetCustomers).

Comment: @Karel: That's going to be the problem.  That function wrapper is necessary for JSONP to work.  It's not a jQuery issue, but that your WCF service isn't returning JSONP when called via SSL for some reason.  How does your WCF service implement that JSONP support?

Comment: @Dave: Indeed, I was missing an endpoint.  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so anyone that comes across this in the future doesn't struggle with this as I did, the answer to this is to add the security tag in your config file as follows:

```
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>

<binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" >

<security mode ="Transport">
<transport clientCredentialType= "None" />
</security>

</binding>
</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

When I had this problem, I could see in fiddler that calling the rest call with http returned the results with a callback function in the results, but calling the same rest call with https only returned the results, which were not wrapped in the callback function.

Here is an example of what i was setting in fiddler and is as symptom that you have this problem.

HTTPS REST CALL:

https://mydomain.com/service.svc/GetState?callback=jQuery171014469725495108632_1368658094950&_=1368658098533

RETURNED:
"{\"statename\":null,\"stateid\":null,\"region\":null}"

HTTP REST CALL:
http://mydomain.com/service.svc/GetState?callback=jQuery171013910021002618056_1368658212752&_=1368658215502

RETURNED:
jQuery171013910021002618056_1368658212752("{\"statename\":null,\"stateid\":null,\"region\":null);

You can see that the https call didn't correctly wrap the result with the jquery callback function.  Using the security tag fixed it.  Hope this helps the next guy.  Robert